# whether it is possible to work through the object id

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two identical functions. The only difference in them - first transmitted UITextField, and the second UILabel.

```
-(void)shakeAnimationField:(UITextField*) textField;
-(void)shakeAnimationLabel:(UILabel*) textField;
```

Can I transfer the id to work with him?
Like `-(void)shakeAnimationLabel:(id) textField;`
I tried, but just got an error

> Property 'transform' not found on object of type 'const __strong id'

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use a message, not a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like yours, I would do something like this:

**Method Declaration:**

```
-(void)shakeAnimationObject:(id) myObject;
```

**Method Definition:**

```
-(void)shakeAnimationObject:(id) myObject
{
   if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
   {
    //My Custom Code for UITextField
   }

   else if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
   {
    //My Custom code for UILabel
   }

   else{
   //What if it is something else???
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dot syntax does not work with `id`.   The dot syntax requires the object to be strongly typed to a class.

So, instead of:

```
textField.transform = ...;
```

Do:

```
[textField setTransform:...];
```

Comment: i write [textField setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translate, 0)]; and recive error Multiple methods named 'setTransform:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
- (void)shakeAnimationForView:(UIView *)view
```

Because both of the classes are subclasses of `UIView` and it defines the interface you want to use.